# html insertar imagen base64 externa

Tags: html, imagen

Necesito insertar una imagen que esta en base64 en un api externo.

ej de la imagen cuando ingreso a apiexterno.com/4566

`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAO8AA...`

yo se que siempre lo hago de esta manera:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...">
```

pero como lo hago de manera externa?

en una imagen común seria en el src colocar la url a la imagen pero en este caso la imagen no tiene el tag data:image/png;base64, adelante de la imágen.

Comment: No tiene el tag porque tu api no lo devuelve. O cambias el controller para que devuelva eso o le añades tú el `data:image/png;base64,`, eso si... si sabes el tipo de imagen, si te lo inventas lo mismo no funciona.

Comment: Hola, el api es externa no puedo modificar el controller y el tipo es png todas eso si lo se

Comment: y porque no concatenas con `data:image/png;base64,` y ya?

Comment: necesitas obtener primero la imagen o string de la imagen ... como lo haces??? si eso no lo has hecho es el 99% del trabajo ... lo demas ya es concatenacion de datos que se puede hacer en javascript o en el backend para que vaya pre armado ...